# Is there a workaround to use gapi.auth2 for authentication when using gapi.drive.realtime?

Tags: javascript, google-authentication, google-drive-realtime-api

There is a bug in gapi.drive.realtime which causes it to not work with auth2 ([See this Github issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/287#issuecomment-307843633).) Here is a brief explanation of the bug; when using the old `gapi.auth.authorize` method, the functions provided by `gapi.drive.realtime` work fine:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: 'client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    immediate: true
}, (response) => {
    if(response.error) {
        console.log("Error signing in!");
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        gapi.drive.realtime.load("file-id", (r) => console.log(r));
    }
});
```

The realtime session is created and the resulting document object is logged to the console with no errors. However, if this code is changed to use the equivalent function in `gapi.auth2`:

```
gapi.auth2.authorize({
    client_id: 'client-id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    prompt: 'none'
}, (response) => {
    if(response.error) {
        console.log("Error signing in!");
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        gapi.drive.realtime.load("file-id", (r) => console.log(r));
    }
});
```

The login completes sucessfully, but when connecting to the file, the following error is logged:

```
GET https://drive.google.com/otservice/gs?rctype=js&rcver=0&id=file-id 401 ()
api:452 Drive Realtime API Error: token_refresh_required: The OAuth token must be refreshed.
```

Looking at the network debugger, the real difference between the first and second attempts is that during the second attempt, `gapi.drive.realtime` does not send an `access_token` in the header, presumably because it is looking for it in `gapi.auth` and not `gapi.auth2`. This is the bug. Authorizing with `gapi.auth2.init` also displays the same behavior.

What I would like to know is if there is a known fix for this bug. Is there some code I could use to make `gapi.drive.realtime` work with the functions in `gapi.auth2`, or will I just have to use `gapi.auth`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the sample in this [github google sample](https://github.com/googledrive/drive-music-player/blob/master/js/dmp.auth.js) on how to implement refreshing of tokens as that seems to be the problem you're encountering.

```
dmp.auth.conditionalRefreshAuth = function() {
  // We refresh the access token about 10 minutes before it expires.
  if (new Date().getTime() + 600000 > dmp.auth.accessTokenExpieryTimestamp) {
    dmp.auth.autoRefreshAuth();
  }
};
```

Comment: Dear @noogui Could you update that URL to the documentation? As it's broken and I have the same problem so would love to check it out!!